# p-dropdown prime-ng valor por defecto o de seleccion no se muestra formulario reactivo

Tags: angular, primeng

Hola muchachos soy nuevo en prime-ng he usado primefaces por mucho tiempo pero tengo un problema ahora con esta tecnologia, quiero usar un p-dropdown de prime-ng este se alimenta de una lista de servicio http, esa parte esta bien pero el problema esta en que al formulario reactivo al abrirse en pantalla a traves de un dialog el mismo no trae cual es la opcion que viene por defecto seleccionada en bd a pesar de que si la imprimo por console.log si aparece, y no se si es el componente y no existe forma de hacer esto.

componente.html.

```
 <p-dialog [(visible)]="userDialogMod" [style]="{heigth: '700px'}" header="Modificar Usuario" [modal]="true" styleClass="p-fluid">

<form class="p-fluid" novalidate [formGroup]="formMod" (submit)="updateUser()">

    <div class="p-field">
        <label for="name">{{'home.login.user' | translate}} *</label>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="false" style="text-transform: lowercase;" pInputText id="name" formControlName="username" required />
        <small><app-validacion-auth [formaGeneric]="formMod.get('username')"></app-validacion-auth></small>
    </div>
    <div class="p-field">
        <label for="estatus">{{'generic.option.status' | translate}} *</label>
        <p-dropdown dataKey="code" appendTo="body" inputId="estatus" [options]="statuses" optionLabel="name" optionValue="code" placeholder="Seleccione..." formControlName="nameStatus"></p-dropdown>
    </div>

    <span class="p-buttonset">
        <button pButton type="button" class="p-button-danger" label="Cancelar" icon="pi pi-trash" (click)="hideDialog()"></button>
        <button pButton type="submit" class="p-button-success" label="Guardar" icon="pi pi-check" [disabled]="!formMod.valid"></button>
    </span>
</form>
```

componente.ts

```
 @Component({
  elector: 'app-usuario',
  templateUrl: './usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usuario.component.scss']
 })
 export class UsuarioComponent implements OnInit {

  formAdd:FormGroup;

  formMod:FormGroup;


   constructor() {
          console.log("Constructor Usuario");
          this.formAdd = new FormGroup({
            "username": new FormControl("", [Validators.required,ValidatorCustom.valid_user]),
            "bandera": new FormControl(false,Validators.required)
          });
          this.formMod = new FormGroup({
            "id": new FormControl(),
            "username": new FormControl(),
            "codeStatus": new FormControl(),
            "nameStatus": new FormControl()
          });
 }

 openUpdate(usuario: SsUser) {
  this.refreshMod();
  this.formMod.patchValue(usuario);
  console.log("valor mod: "+this.formMod.get("nameStatus").value);
  this.userDialogMod = true;
 }
```

}

class

```
  export class SsUser {

id: number;
username: string;
passwordUser: string;
passwordNew: string;
attempt: number;
idStatus: number;
codeStatus: string;
nameStatus: string;
typeStatus: number;
encryptKey: string;
codUser: string;
registryNew: boolean;

}
```

[image: se hace click en modificar en registro estatus bloqueado]

[image: se habre dialog pero muestra primer registro de la lista mas no registro guardado en formcontrolname]

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema usando p-dropdown dentro de un reactive form. Lo que me solucionó el problema fue agregar la propiedad dataKey="value" para que el p-dropdown entendiera que tenia que tomar el valor del FormControl alojado en el atributo value.

HTML del formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objecto del formgroup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Referencia que usé para solucionar el problema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853826/13025171)